# How to count the recurrence of an array value

Tags: php

I want to count the recurrence of a true or false and output which has the most. Is there a predefined function to do this in PHP? So far I have done it like this (`isHappy()` method):

```
class Girl {
    private $issues = [];
    public function addIssue($details) {
        this->issues[] = [$details, false];
        return;
    }
    public function isHappy() {
        $true = [];
        $false = [];
        foreach($this->issues as $issue) {
            if($issue[1]) { $true[] = true; } else { $false[] = false; }
        }
        // what if its == to one another? do we return happy or sad?
        return count($true) < count($false) ? false : true;
    }
    public function resolveIssue() {
        for($i = 0; $i <= count($this->issues); $i++) {
            if(!$this->issues[$i][1]) {
                 $this->issues[$i][1] = true;
                 break;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

So when I run it, I can get the average of if she is happy or not:

```
$her = new Girl();

$her->addIssue('Deleted our messages');
$her->addIssue('Over reacted');
$her->addIssue('Told her family to pretty much **** off');

echo $her->isHappy() ? 'it is all ok:)' : 'she hates u, hang urself.';
```

P.S: It should probably return false every time cos you can't win.

Comment: `array_count_values` ?

Comment: if it should return false every time then why are you even counting? what exactly is your question to you seem to have achieved what your title states..

Comment: `It should probably return false every time cos you can't win.` was a joke to say girls are impossible to understand @Pamblam

Comment: Youre talking to programmers. We take everything literally.

Comment: LOL you make me laff, im playing @CandiedOrange xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
function isHappy(array $issues) {
    $happiness = array_count_values(array_map('intval', $issues));
    return $happiness[1] > $happiness[0];
}
print_r(
    isHappy([ true, false, true, true, false ])
);
```

[See it live on 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/Aa0U3)

Note that `array_count_values` only works on string and int, so I'm mapping the given `boolean` to `int` for processing.

Comment: Nice, this helped. & I've read the documentation on it also. Thanks. +1 & marked when I can.

Comment: Glad it helped, it is indeed a helpful function for bucketing data.

Answer (score 2):

`array_sum()` type juggles for you, so simply compare the sum of all `true` with all issues minus the `true` (which yields all `false`):

```
public function isHappy() {
    return ($true = array_sum($this->issues)) > (count($this->issues) - $true);
}
```

Get the keys where the value is `true` and count it, do the same for `false` and compare:

```
return count(array_keys($this->issues, true)) > count(array_keys($this->issues, false));
```

Or a number of other possible combinations.